# Is there an equivalent to sp_getapplock, sp_releaseapplock in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, locking

In MSSQL I am using sp_getapplock, sp_releaseapplock.

How can I achieve the same functionality in PostgreSql?

Comment: [Advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) maybe? I don't know what those SQL Server procedures are doing

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link 
https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/07/postgresql-concurrency-isolation-and-locking/

Look at locking in PostgreSQL found all locking option here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html

Answer (score -1):

PostgresSql follows a MVCC model. So the database itself will take care of locking/updating resources.

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CALL-XePNn4cfD_80aaXZg%3DHb1zWo1VpcZCH3K%2BUdaD9gWcZQ5A%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: `sp_getapplock` etc aren't about locking data.