# waitlist in postgres, deadlock

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking, deadlock

I'm trying to create a waiting list in Postgres. Minimal code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS applies(
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    user_id SMALLINT REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    service_id SMALLINT REFERENCES services(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    status SMALLINT DEFAULT 0, --0: new 1: waitlisted, 2: applied
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, service_id)
    -- ...
);

CREATE INDEX ON applies (service_id);
```

status is important, because I want to be able to notify users when they are applied after waitlisted. But don't want to notify them based on that they are in the first `n` position if they wasn't waitlisted at all.
Services are limited to a given number of users. There are multiple choices how the system decides which user gets the service. The simplest is first come first served. That's the reason it has two phases (but it shouldn't change the use case in any way).

Possible requests are:

1. Insert: a user applies/enrolls for a service

   1. Inserting (`user_id`, `service_id`, `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`, `state: 0 (new)`)
   2. a Updating state to 1 (waitlisted) or 2 (applied) based on the COUNT(*) with the same service_id
2. Remove: a user cancels his/her application for a service

   1. Removing the given application
   2. If there's someone in waitlisted state, move to applied, and send notification about it

My first try was a naive implementation. Let's say service limit is 10.

1/2 OnAdd:

```
UPDATE applies
SET status = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <= 10 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
    FROM applies
    WHERE service_id = 7918
    AND created <= '2021-08-16 16:20:34.161274+00:00:00'
)
WHERE user_id = 5070
AND service_id = 7918
RETURNING status
```

2/2 OnRemove:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM applies
WHERE status = 1
AND service_id = 7915
ORDER BY created
LIMIT 1
```

and then ( I know they could be joined)

```
UPDATE applies
SET status = 2
WHERE status = 1
AND user_id = 5063
AND service_id = 7915
```

It worked for a sequential test, but the multi-threading test showed cases when there were more than 10 rows with applied state.

So I put them in a transaction started with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, then `REPEATABLE READ`, they gave me a lot of `ERROR #40001 could not serialize access due to concurrent update`. Then the same with `READ COMMITTED`. It was way much better, than the naive version, but it ended in over-applications as well.

Then I started using `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` in selects instead, but they always ended in a deadlock very soon. I searched a lot on deadlocks, but couldn't find anything useful.

So I came up with a version, where OnAdd and OnRemove had very similar queries, only differing in selecting `user_id`, where I didn't add `FOR UPDATE`. I had to change 1/1 Insert so the default state is waitlisted.

OnAdd:

```
UPDATE applies
SET status = 2
WHERE service_id = 7860
AND 10 > (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT service_id, user_id
        FROM applies
        WHERE service_id = 7860
        AND status = 2
        FOR NO KEY UPDATE
    ) as newstate)
AND user_id = 5012 RETURNING status
```

OnRemove:

```
UPDATE applies
SET status = 2
WHERE service_id = 7863
AND 10 > (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT service_id, user_id
        FROM applies
        WHERE service_id = 7863
        AND status = 2
        FOR NO KEY UPDATE
    ) as newstate)
AND user_id = (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM applies
    WHERE service_id = 7863
    And status = 1
    ORDER BY created
    LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING user_id
```

But in the multi-threading test it ended up in a deadlock too.

**Edit:**

As [melcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68930831/6155997) suggested below, I added a column instead of counting. Not to a separate table, but inside `services`.

I added a transaction to OnAdd and OnRemove that starts with

```
SELECT *
FROM services
WHERE id = ?
FOR NO KEY UPDATE
```

Sometimes in the multithreading test it under-applied. So I joined Remove to be in the same transaction with OnRemove, and that works finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you're trying to do and how databases work - you're going to need a shared resource that gets locked OnAdd.

The reason is that two threads that are both trying to 'add' at the same time must compete for a shared resource so that only one of them wins and the other errors / fails. You cannot accomplish your goal using a count of rows.

One solution would be a locks table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS applies(
    service_id SMALLINT REFERENCES services(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    applied_count SMALLINT
);
```

And then:

1. Open transaction (if outside of a procedure)
2. Acquire an exclusive/write lock to services row in the lock table
3. IF the limit/constraint is satisfied (e.g. applied_count < 10) then...
4. Mark the "applies" as applied `UPDATE applies SET status = 2`
5. Update lock table (e.g. `SET applied_count = applied_count + 1`)
6. Commit transaction

Comment: Have a close look at Advisory Locks https://stackoverflow.com/q/59322348/4116017 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS

Comment: I hadn’t used advisory locks but they look great! Looks like they’re more performant as well. Can they only be identified numerically? Seems a bit frustrating to use for different use cases and not be able to namespace them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with Postgres and I never used advisory locks myself. I used only `sp_getapplock` in MS SQL Server and those have names 255 characters long. I learned that there is such a thing as "advisory locks" in Postgres only today when I searched for "postgres sp_getapplock". I suggested them because they are built into the engine specifically for dealing with concurrency and may be better in some cases than a custom-made locks table.

Comment: I think that it just adds a new layer, that will have the very same problem. The `applied_count` needs to be read and written, just the same as apply rows. OnAdd would increase it, OnRemove would select, then keep or decrease. If you could specify it a bit more, with exact OnAdd and OnRemove queries, I could give it a try.

Comment: The problem you’re running into is a concurrency problem. Concurrent execution of your queries will both pass the count check and then both update the status, causing you to exceed the desired limit. So you need to acquire an exclusive lock to a shared resource when running the the check / updating the status. Not sure I’ll have time to provide example queries / procedures today, possibly this weekend.

Comment: I started to implement this, it looks good until I need to choose a waitlisted user in OnRemove, which is another concurrency problem.